# How do I put data in multidimensional array from existing files C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create a program for my church who gets songs from a save file.
But I don't know how to put that data into an multidimensional array.
Below are the things I want to be put into an array. Is that possible?
(I'm new to C#)

```
<items>
  <CMediaBase xsi:type="CSong">
     <DisplayTitle>Eigen bundel 10 - In Jesus name</DisplayTitle>
     <IsDirty>false</IsDirty>
     <SwapLanguages>false</SwapLanguages>
     <SongLanguage>Both</SongLanguage>
     <MediaType>Song</MediaType>
     <Number>10</Number>
     <SelectedVersion>MyVersion</SelectedVersion>
     <SongBookName>Eigen bundel</SongBookName>
     <ThemeName>OPS</ThemeName>
     <Title>In Jesus name</Title>
  </CMediaBase>
</items>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a multi-dimensional array? They are rarely useful and I can't see how they would be in this circumstance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not using the appropriate data structures to solve the problem.

A two-dimensional array will not solve the problem here which boils down to parsing your songs XML file and transforming that data representation to something that you can use in C#.

I propose to represent your songs with a C# class, something like this:

```
[XmlRoot("SongList")]
public class SongList
{
    [XmlElement("Song")]
    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{
    [XmlElement("DisplayTitle")]
    public string DisplayTitle { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IsDirty")]
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SwapLanguage")]
    public bool SwapLanguage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SongLanguage")]
    public string SongLanguage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MediaType")]
    public string MediaType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SongBookName")]
    public string SongBookName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ThemeName")]
    public string ThemeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Please note the use of the **[XmlElement]** and **[XmlRoot]** attributes, which allow us to specify to the XML serializer how to parse your XML representation to a C# representation of that XML.

Now using an XML string like the following :

```
 string xml = @"<SongList>
 <Song>
   <DisplayTitle> Eigen bundel 10 - In Jesus name</DisplayTitle>
   <IsDirty > false </IsDirty>
   <SwapLanguages >false </SwapLanguages>
   <SongLanguage > Both </SongLanguage >
   <MediaType >Song</MediaType >
   <Number>10</Number >
   <SelectedVersion >MyVersion</SelectedVersion >
   <SongBookName > Eigen bundel</SongBookName >
   <ThemeName >OPS</ThemeName >
   <Title >In Jesus name</Title>
 </Song>
 <Song>
   <DisplayTitle > Song 2</DisplayTitle >
   <IsDirty > true </IsDirty >
   <SwapLanguages > false </SwapLanguages >
   <SongLanguage > Both </SongLanguage >
   <MediaType > Song </MediaType >
   <Number > 10 </Number >
   <SelectedVersion > MyVersion </SelectedVersion >
   <SongBookName > Eigen bundel </SongBookName >
   <ThemeName > OPS </ThemeName >
   <Title > In Jesus name</Title >
   </Song>
 </SongList>";
```

You can then use the C# serializer to deserialize this XML representation to the object representation as follows:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SongList));

using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
   var albums = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as SongList;
}
```

If you want to read a text file you should load the file into a FileStream and deserialize it like this:

```
using (var fs= new FileStream("<YOUR XML FILE PATH>", FileMode.Open)) 
{
  var songList = serializer.Deserialize(fs) as SongList;
}
```

Note that you should be importing the following namespaces to be able to use the XML serializer and the FileStream class :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```